# Deep copy without Serialize

Tags: c#, generics, serialization, unity-game-engine, binaryformatter

I'm trying to copy two diferent instances of the same class, without the reference, i dont know why thats is so hard to do, just copy and ok, good bye yea?

btw i found a script with binnaryformatter that does what i want, but in my class i have a variable of type Texture2D and when i press play i have a error saying that Texture2D is not marked as serializable.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

public class pichota : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<Pig> johnPigList = new List<Pig>();
    public List<Pig> peterPigList = new List<Pig>();

    void Start () {
        List<Pig> templist = Clone(johnPigList);
        peterPigList = templist;
    }

    public List<Pig> Clone(List<Pig> source)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, source);
            ms.Seek(0, 0);
            return (List<Pig>)bf.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }

    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.G))
        {

            peterPigList[0].number += 2;
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Pig
{
    public int number;
}
```

is there another way to deep copy, or just serialize texture 2d ? dont laugh on me, im new to this advanced stuff

Comment: Add more info about which class to copy. Is it from your own code, what range of members etc.

Comment: why not make a Pig constructor that takes Pig as an argument and copies members in the constructor?

Comment: wow rudolf, i passed one day and one night trying to solve this, and its a very simple solution !

Comment: Its better to have a function called deepcopy or shallowcopy than a clone or a copy constructor since it should be obvious what is done

Comment: @Imapler, your naming convention is theoretically better, but reality dictates that you will have mixed (shallow and deep) member copies, so its never as simple as you suggest. In fact following your naming convention he would probably end up with deepcopy, deepercopy and notsodeepcopy functions to describe what he is doing.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why do you need to have a bunch of cloned textures. It seems weird to me and I imagine stuff like procedurally animated images.

Normally, you can't serialize texture in Unity. AFAIK it just don't work that way. But you may turn texture in to byte array with **Texture2D.EncodeToPNG** and serialize it instead.

Anyway, in editor mode Unity allows you to clone different objects with [CopySerialized](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.CopySerialized.html). Also, there are some undocumented functions used to copy components:

```
UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.CopyComponent(copiedComponent);
UnityEditorInternal.ComponentUtility.PasteComponentAsNew(targetGameObject);
```

In player mode, if you want to clone arbitrary object then the best way is to use reflection instead of serialization.